# have a 'belongsTo' without a 'hasMany' in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, has-many, belongs-to

Im building a Grails app (I use version 2.0.3) and I would like to have a “belongsTo” without a “hasMany”

I have:

- A domain class called **User** which holds user information and is used for login to the system
- (A domain class called **Role** holding different Roles in the system)
- A domain class called **Parent**
- A domain class called **Teacher**

What I would like to do is to connect the **Parent** and **Teacher** to the **User** so that they can login to the system. My Idea was to add this:

```
class User{
    String username 
    String password
    String firstName
    String lastName
}

Class Parent{
    static belongsTo = [user:User]
    String favoriteColor
}


Class Teacher{
    static belongsTo = [user:User]
    String favoriteBook
}
```

So, as you can see the user does not have any information about **Parent** or **Teacher**

In the database, the **Parent** and **Teacher** as a reference to the **User** (user_id), and this looks good.

The problem occurs when I try to delete the **Teacher** (for example). The row is deleted in that table but there is still a row in the **User** table.

If I, on the other hand, try to delete the user, Ill get:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bad design (belongsTo without hasMany)? I really would not like to have **Parent** or **Teacher** info in the **User** class since the **User** should be ‘clean’

Comment: Can you not extend `User` from `Parent` and `Teacher`?

Comment: I assume you mean Parent extends User and Teacher extends User?

Comment: @ Aseem: And use: **tablePerHierarchy false**
in the User class ? So I will get separate tables

Comment: @Assem: So is this the prefered way to solve this type of use case? I mean, the use case should be pretty normal and several other programmers should have had similar cases

Comment: Every `Parent` and `Teacher` is a `User` in your system. Correct? That by itself is the definition of inheritance. A `Parent` does not belong to a `User` but is a `User`. Are the tables already existing? Why the concern?

Comment: @Assem: Exactly, every Parent/Teacher is a user and should be able to login. Yes, unfortunately user/teacher/parent tables already exist so I have to do some migration in order to get this to work. I agree with you, extending from User is the most logic way to solve this.

Comment: Then why can you not have hasMany? Is this homework?

Comment: No, no homework. I dont want the user domain class to have code connected to a Teacher or Parent. I would prefer to have the User class as clean as possible, just having code which actually belongs there. This is why I dont want the User class to have 2 'hasMany' properties saying Teacher and Parent. If I would have that I would end up with a User object which either have many parents or many teachers which is not correct.

Comment: Then you can use hasOne.

Comment: Yes I can use haveOne but still: The User class will have information about a Teacher and a Parent which I dont think is correct. From an object programming perspective I don’t think this is good. If a developer would query the database for a User (instead of a Teacher or Parent) he/she would end up with an User object which holds at least one null reference. If the object is a Teacher, the Parent reference would be null and vice versa. So, to make the code cleaner and to make it more understandable I don’t think adding haveOne for the Teacher and Parent is good

Comment: may be u should try a user accont belogns to either a teacher or a parent. hence, out `hasOne` instead of `belongsTo`

Comment: Why not make Parent and Teacher as Roles? That's how I understand it should be from your use case. Otherwise, just extend the User class.